# Tool to extract flatten DOM

Tags: dom, shadow-dom

DevTools in newer browsers display the light and shadow DOM. But what seems to be missing is a "Copy flatten DOM" that captures the `#shadow-root` along with the root elements.

I've sorted out how to, for example, display the shadow DOM in DevTools, but Copy Element only copies the light DOM.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Copy the `shadowRoot.innerHTML` in a `<template>` element.

2) For each `<slot>` element, get the distributed content with the `assignedNodes()` method and replace the `<slot>` (with `replaceChild()`) by it.

```js
var sh = host.attachShadow({mode:'open'})
sh.innerHTML = `<h4>Shadow DOM</h4> Content: <div><slot name="node1"></slot></div>`
  
function slotContent( slot )
{
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment()   
  var nodes = slot.assignedNodes( { flatten:true } ) 
  for ( let node of nodes )
  {
    frag.appendChild( node.cloneNode( true ) ) 
  }
  return frag
}

function flatten()
{
  var template = document.createElement( 'template' )
  template.innerHTML = host.shadowRoot.innerHTML   
  var slots = Array.from( host.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll( 'slot' ) )
  var slots2 = Array.from( template.content.querySelectorAll( 'slot' ) )
  for ( var i in slots )
  {
    var frag = slotContent( slots[i] )
    slots2[i].parentNode.replaceChild( frag, slots2[i] )
  } 
  console.log( template.innerHTML )
}
```

```html
<div id=host>
  <span slot=node1>Distributed Node</span>
</div>
<button onclick=flatten()>Flatten</button>
```